# SQL Server foreign relationship on two-column primary key

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following three sample tables (simplified demo for purpose of question):

```
CREATE TABLE Teams 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE TeamGroups 
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    TeamId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id,TeamId)
)

CREATE TABLE RoomBookings
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    TeamGroupId int NOT NULL,
    RoomId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

and I have the following foreign key already set up:

```
ALTER TABLE TeamGroups WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TeamGroups_Teams] 
    FOREIGN KEY (TeamId) REFERENCES Teams(Id)
```

The idea is that each `Team` can be in zero or more `TeamGroups`, and each `TeamGroup` can have zero or more `RoomBookings`

To reflect that, I want to add a foreign key from the `RoomBookings` table into the `TeamGroups` table.

I tried using the Relationships GUI in Management Studio to create the foreign key (primary key table: `TeamGroups.ID`, foreign key table: `RoomBookings.TeamGroupId`) but I get an error:

> The columns in table 'TeamGroups' do not match an existing primary key
>   or UNIQUE constraint

I'm assuming it's because the `TeamGroups` table has a two-column primary key?

I don't really want to make a foreign key constraint from the `TeamGroups` table (eg, the key is present in the `TeamGroups` table), as the table will eventually be used by other tables (such as `EquipmentBookings`, `GroupManagers`, etc).

Any help?

Comment: If your primary key is made up from more than one columns, then **all** foregin keys also **must have** all those columns - there's no way around this. But I don't understand why you'd get this error trying to link `TeamGroups` to `Team` based on the `Team.Id` column.... that should work just fine.

Comment: It works fine linking `TeamGroups` to `Team`. It's `TeamGroups` to `RoomBookings` that fails.

Comment: I've updated the statement shown.. I used Management Studio to script it out but mangled it when copy+pasting. Ignore that SQL entirely, it's not the problem - it's there to demonstrate the other key that already exists. What I want to do is add a key from `RoomBookings` to `TeamGroups`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your primary key is made up from more than one columns, then **all** foregin keys also **must have** all those columns - there's no way around this.

But I don't understand why you'd get this error trying to link `TeamGroups` to `Team` based on the `Team.Id` column.... that should work just fine.

Try using this:

```
ALTER TABLE TeamGroups WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TeamGroups_Teams] 
   FOREIGN KEY (TeamId) REFERENCES Teams(Id);
```

You had `Teams` (which is not a valid column in `TeamGroups` at all), and you had `REFERENCES Teams.id` which is wrong - it needs to be `REFERNCES Teams(Id);` (column in parenthesis - not the "dot" notation)

**Update:** from  `TeamGroups` to `RoomBookings` - yes.... either use both columns from `TeamGroups` in your `RoomBookings` table - or what would stop you from making the `TeamGroups.Id` column an `INT IDENTITY` and then have the PK on just this one column?? Any good reason for that??

```
CREATE TABLE TeamGroups 
(
    TeamGroupId int NOT NULL,
    TeamId int NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (TeamGroupId)
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.RoomBookings
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RoomBookings_TeamGroup
   FOREIGN KEY TeamGroupId REFERENCES TeamGroups(TeamGroupId)
```

Comment: TeamGroups can consist of one or more Teams. Eg, TeamGroup 1 can contain Team A and Team B, meaning there would be two rows in TeamGroup, both with an Id of 1, but with a different value in TeamId.

Comment: @Sk93: can any given team be part of more than one teamgroup? If so, then you need to make `TeamGroup` a proper data table and put a m:n relationship table between `Team` and `TeamGroup`. If not - if one team is only ever part of a single `TeamGroup` (or none), then your relationship is backwards - it should be from `Team` to  `TeamGroups` (`Team` should have the `TeamGroupId` column - not the other  way around)

Comment: Yes it can. I'll adjust. Thanks.